# How to append value to list in a row based on another column python?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe that looks like:

```
        body              label
   the sky is blue        [noun]
   the apple is red.      [noun]
   Let's take a walk      [verb]
```

I want to add an item to the list in label depending on if there is a color in the body column.

Desired Output:

```
            body              label
       the sky is blue        [noun, color]
       the apple is red.      [noun, color]
       Let's take a walk      [verb]
```

I have tried:

```
data.loc[data.body.str.contains("red|blue"), 'label'] = data.label.str.append('color')
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One option is to use `apply` on the Series and then directly append to list:

```
data.loc[data.body.str.contains('red|blue'), 'label'].apply(lambda lst: lst.append('color'))

data
                body          label
0    the sky is blue  [noun, color]
1  the apple is red.  [noun, color]
2  Let's take a walk         [verb]
```

Comment: this works. thanks!

Comment: @mpatil Cool. Glad to hear!